# how can i print data of array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here are my codes:

```
app.get('/index/:name',function(req, res){
    data = connection.query('SELECT * FROM deneme', function(err, rows, fields){
        if(err) throw err;
        veri = rows;
        return veri;
    });

    console.log(data);

    res.render('index', {
        title: req.params.name,
        para: data
    });
});
```

When i call `localhost:8080/index/example` it returns `[object Object]` 
I want to print data of array, how can i do this?

I can do it when I'm using php with print_r() function..

Meantime, array's data:

```
Id Name
1  yab
2  sad
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OP just want to print the data for debugging purposes, for that you can use the following cross-browser way that uses JSON to print a nice representation of the data:

```
console.log( JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
for (var colName in data) {
    console.log("column " + colName);
    var rows = data[colName];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        console.log(rows[i]);
    }
}
```

You will have to tweak it for your needs, that's the general way to iterate such objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the result collection and print the attributes

```
      $.each(resultArray, function() {
             this.id;//use this to write id
             this.name;//use this to write name
       });
```

Comment: @user1870012 This is JQuery syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To output to the console you could do something like:

```
for(var index in data) {
    var item = data[index];
    var output = [];
    for(var field in item) {
        output.push(item[field]);
    }
    console.log(output.join("\t"));
}
```

For outputting in html, you'd do something like similar, but creating actual HTML nodes. Maybe, something like:

```
var output = ["<table>"];
for(var index in data) {
    output.push("<tr>");
    var item = data[index];
    for(var field in item) {
        output.push("<td>");
        output.push(item[field]);
        output.push("</td>");
    }
    output.push("</tr>");
    console.log(output.join("\t"));
}
output.push("</table>");
element.innerHTML = output.join("");
```

I've not tried that in a browser, so there might be a couple of mistakes, but that should do it.

Let me know if you'd like any more help.